# data member should be written in initialization list in the constructor? Different implementaion for array and vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, initializer-list

While creating a vector of defined size for further use in class, is it neccessary that the parameter for constructors of data members should be written in the initializer list of my class' constructor?

Why does

```
class MyHashMap {
public:
    vector<int> vec;
    MyHashMap():vec(1000001) {
        fill(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 1000000, -1);
    }
```

works but,

```
class MyHashMap {
public:
    vector<int> vec(1000001);
    MyHashMap() {
        fill(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 1000000, -1);
    }
```

does not work and gives an error like

```
Line 4: Char 22: error: expected parameter declarator
    vector<int> vec (1000001);
                     ^
```

If the same implementation is done using arrays,

```
class MyHashMap {
public:
    int data[1000001];
    MyHashMap() {
        fill(data, data + 1000000, -1);
    }
```

there is no issue.

I'm  still a beginner at c++ if someone could help me that'd be awesome. Thanks

Comment: As an aside, vector already has a fill constructor. So `vec(1000001, -1)` - in the member initializer list would be equivalent and shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use parenthesis to pass parameters to a class member's constructor directly in its declaration inline, like you are trying to.  You need to either:

- use the parent class's member initialization list:

```cpp
class MyHashMap {
public:
    vector<int> vec;
    MyHashMap() : vec(1000001, -1) {}
```

- in C++11 and later, you can either use an initializer:

```cpp
class MyHashMap {
public:
    vector<int> vec = vector<int>(1000001, -1);
    MyHashMap() = default;
```

- or, you can use curly braces instead of parenthesis:

```cpp
class MyHashMap {
public:
    vector<int> vec{1000001, -1};
    MyHashMap() = default;
```

Note, however, that in this last case, because `std::vector` has a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list` as input, this syntax will actually create the vector using just 2 elements whose values are `1000001` and `-1`, it will not call the 2-param constructor to create the vector with 1000001 elements of value `-1`.

Comment: @Scheff good catch, I keep forgetting about that. I have updated my answer

Comment: "You can't use parenthesis to pass parameters to a class member's constructor in its declaration, like you are trying to." I'm not sure if I follow. 
In my post why does the **second code snippet**, the one having **`vector<int> vec (1000001);`** doesn't work but the the final code snippet, the one with simple **array implementation `int data[1000001];`** works. I might be missing something obvious here, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @PrasanjeetKeshri a plain C style array is just setting aside a chunk of fixed memory, it does not have a constructor. A vector does. You can't use parenthesis to call a constructor on a class member declaration, there is simply no syntax that allows that.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!